# Does Windows Update modify Hosts file?

Tags: antivirus, windows-10, updates, hosts-file

I have Avira installed with Hosts file protection enabled.

I've noticed a pattern where Avira warns me of an attempted modification of the Hosts file (but alas doesn't tell me which process did the attempt), and soon afterwards a Windows Update notification pops up.

Is this normal? Does this mean the attempt to modify the Hosts file came from Windows Update (for some security-related reason, etc)?

The closest subject I've seen on SE is this question, where apparently Windows Defender was involved: [Something is changing my hosts file without asking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/something-is-changing-my-hosts-file-without-asking)

Comment: Have you tried the accepted answer of the question you link?

Comment: Alas no, because I only see one notification. There's no further attempt to modify the hosts file afterwards (perhaps until the next update). So, because I don't have a time machine, I'd need to have Process Monitor running all the time (though I could possibly do something more clever like starting it every Patch Tuesday, but the latest occurrence was today).

Comment: It's probably Microsoft trying to fix what those pesky kids are doing; turning off telemetry and shiny new Windows features.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - You install Windows 8.
> - You change the Hosts file by specifying custom IP-address-to-host-name mappings to prevent users from browsing to
>     some websites.
> - You run a scan in Microsoft Windows Defender.
>
> In this scenario, the Hosts file is detected as a
>   SettingsModifier:Win32/PossibleHostsFileHijack malware threat by
>   Windows Defender.

[Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/gl-es/help/2764944/hosts-file-is-detected-as-malware-in-windows-defender)

So when the host file is being restored by Windows Defender, Avira's host file protection could be detecting the change.

Comment: Thanks for the succestion. I have run a few Windows Defender scans, it does not appear to try and change the Hosts file.